# What are the most commonly consumed solid foods on the space station and why?

Tags: astronaut-lifestyle, food

Clearly, an astronaut’s diet varies from day to day to ensure proper health while in space.  And depending on the astronaut’s place of origin,  preferences, and availability, their choice of foods will also vary.  But I wonder if there are commonalities among the various astronauts in terms of foods that most tend to consume while in space, particularly on the ISS.

What are the most commonly consumed foods on the ISS by astronauts?  More importantly, what characteristics make them the most commonly eaten foods?

I want to limit the scope of this question to foods consumed in solid form, as opposed to liquified foods or beverages.  Is there a ranked list of most commonly consumed foods by astronauts overall on the ISS, independent of country of origin?

Comment: I could help with the opposit: the least liked food on the MIR was a fish dish. ... According to Thomas Reiter. The Crew didn't like it at all, but they run out of other meals and his mission took longer than planned, so alle three had only this fish dish  left for their last days.

Comment: Any food is a most popular astronaut food if you put a sufficient amount of spicy sauce on it

Comment: Tortillas (used to wrap other foods in them), but it is hard to find good data on this. I seem to be unable to google for an itemized cargo manifest of any IIS resupply mission :(

Comment: There should not be crumbs when eating tortillas in zero gravity. @GeorgPatscheider